# AJAX functions returning values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following function but I can't seem to get `returnedData = result` to successfully set the value. If I include `alert(result)` in the same location, the popup displays the string I'm looking for correctly.

Is there something I'm missing here? I had thought because I declared the variable `returnedData` outside the function it would be accessible everywhere?

```
function AJAXprocesstwoVariables(Var1, Var2) {
    var V1 = Var1,
        V2 = Var2;
        var returnedData;
    $.post(
        processinglocation, { 
            data1: V1,
            data2: V2 
        },
        function (result) {
            returnedData = result; // *<- this doesn't work*
            // alert(result); // *<-this works*
        }
    );
    return returnedData;
}

var ReturnedInfo = AJAXprocesstwoVariables(Var1, Var2);
$('body').append(ReturnedInfo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post` will run asynchronously. Once that line is run, the request will be made in the background, and you will immediately hit the return line of `AJAXprocesstwoVariables`. You are attempting to use `returnedData` before it is set in the success function of your `$.post`.

Comment: Thanks for the lead on async. I've got what I needed.